# KeyValuePair vs. NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

There are other questions such as KeyValuePair vs IDictionary, but I feel this one differs slightly.

`NameValueCollection` takes a string key and string value.

`KeyValuePair` is like a dictionary, you tell it what type the key and value is.

I don't understand why `NameValueCollection` exists. Initializing a `KeyValuePair` with string types seems sufficient. I also noticed that `NameValueCollection` has some more methods available to it, but again why not merge both classes into one?

Comment: A `KeyValuePair` not like a dictionary. It is simply a Tuple containing the Key and the Value.

Comment: @pst, a dictionary takes a list of key/value pairs. I'm failing to see a difference.

Comment: @Nick `var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Hello", "World!")`  -- [KeyValuePair<K,V>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)

Comment: @Nick: A dictionary can only have one of every key.

Comment: I believe my misunderstanding was that a dictonary holds key value pairs, where as a key value pair is singular, you can't keep adding to pst's `kvp` example above for instance.

Comment: @Nick: @pst means that A dictionary is a collection of kvps where you can't have duplicate keys, while a kvp is just one instance of a kvp. seems fairly straightforward

Comment: A KeyValuePair stores a single key and a single value. That's it. Not multiple keys vs multiple values... just one of each. It's not a collection, but simply a container for a pair of objects.

Comment: @Nico, @spender, I understand now, thank you for the clearer explanation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A `KeyValuePair` not like a dictionary. It is simply a Tuple containing the Key and the Value.

`NameValueCollection` is wrapper over what *amounts to* a `IList<KeyValuePair<string,IList<string>>>` (note that `NameValueCollection` predates generics) - operations like `Get(string)` are `O(n)` and items can be fetched by index and each Key maps to one *or more* Values (this differs from a `Dictionary<string,string>`).

A reason for this is explained in [the NameValueCollection documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx):

> > This class can be used for headers, query strings and form data.

The newer <del>"replacement"</del> data-structure with *some* similar behavior for `NameValueCollection` is [`Lookup<string,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx). (However, it doesn't directly support the same operations as is immutable as spender notes.)

Happy coding.

Comment: The principal problem with Lookup in this scenario is that it is immutable, unlike NaveValueCollection, which can be added to. As such, it's not really a "replacement", but has similar behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

[NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) existing in .NET 1.0 and 1.1, [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) is a generic type and wasn't added to .NET until 2.0.  All the classes in [System.Collections.Specialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32c13e62.aspx) all predates the addition of generics; it contains certain strongly typed (specialized if you will) for use when that's exactly what you need to users don't have to cast from object to string.

Answer (score 0):

[KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) is the component you use to iterate a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int,long>

foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
{
    // kvp is KeyValuePair<int,long>. kvp.Key is the int key and kvp.Value is the long value for the key
}
```

[NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) is indexable.